# How to map response with objects instead of a list of objects with Spring Boot in Api Client

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

How should I create a class for an api response that returns objects instead of a list of objects? I'm using Spring Boot and RestTemplate and don't know how to go about it.
This is a response:

```
{
   "status":200,
   "data":{
      "1":{
         "id":"1",
         "auth":"manual",
         "confirmed":"1",
         "policyagreed":"0",
         "deleted":"0",
         "suspended":"0",
         "mnethostid":"1",
         "username":"guest",
         "password":"",
         "idnumber":"",
         "firstname":"Guest user",
         "lastname":" ",
         "email":"root@localhost",
         "emailstop":"0",
         "icq":"",
         "skype":"",
         "yahoo":"",
         "aim":"",
         "msn":"",
         "phone1":"",
         "phone2":"",
         "institution":"",
         "department":"",
         "address":"",
         "city":"",
         "country":"",
         "lang":"en",
         "calendartype":"gregorian",
         "theme":"",
         "timezone":"99",
         "firstaccess":"0",
         "lastaccess":"0",
         "lastlogin":"0",
         "currentlogin":"0",
         "lastip":"",
         "secret":"",
         "picture":"0",
         "url":"",
         "description":"",
         "descriptionformat":"1",
         "mailformat":"1",
         "maildigest":"0",
         "maildisplay":"2",
         "autosubscribe":"1",
         "trackforums":"0",
         "timecreated":"0",
         "timemodified":"1584114527",
         "trustbitmask":"0",
         "imagealt":null,
         "lastnamephonetic":null,
         "firstnamephonetic":null,
         "middlename":null,
         "alternatename":null,
         "moodlenetprofile":null
      },
      "2":"...."
   }
}
```

I tried something like this:
public class MoodleResponse {

```
private Integer status;
private Data data;

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

public class Data {

```
private HashMap<String, MoodleUser> map;

public HashMap<String, MoodleUser> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(HashMap<String, MoodleUser> map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

}

It doesn't work. I've never encountered anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a model class here which has all attributes present in response and each attribute must be mapped with @JsonProperty

key here is to understand @JsonPropery annotation
for eg

```
public class Data{
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("auth")
private String auth;
}
```

and soo on